# Chrome 85 devtools device toolbar white box-shadow around window

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

## Update: 15 Feb 2021

It seems that the Chrome team has reverted this change, or at least on my end I don't see the white glow anymore. This is on chrome version `88.0.4324.96` though everything else about my setup is the same. I can't say with any certainty whether this was changed in this version or in a previous major version since I made the original question, though, but perhaps updating to `88` will fix it for others, too.

Here's what SO looks like to me now
[image]

And my own website
[image]

As you can see, no white glow anymore!

---

## Original Post

On Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS, running Google Chrome `85.0.4183.83`, when using the devtools "Device Toolbar" option, I get this horrible white box-shadow around the responsive window. I thought it was my own website and that I somehow set a box-shadow to the `html` element or something, but testing it on a variety of different websites, the box shadow shows up

[image]

It's a lot less obvious when the website doesn't have a dark background, but as you can see from the screenshot of my own website it's very obvious on sites with dark backgrounds, as you can see with Stackoverflow below

[image]

It's not immediately apparent on Google's homepage, however if you look hard enough you'll definitely notice a white glow around the responsive window.

[image]

What could be causing this? It happens even with no extensions active, with a fresh boot of Chrome/Ubuntu, the only thing I haven't tried yet is reinstalling Chrome, but that seems an excessive measure. There either wasn't this white glow in the past, or I just didn't notice it before now (which I doubt).

Comment: Seeing it too. Maybe you could report it on https://crbug.com if it's not there already?

Comment: fyi - the white drop-shadow only shows up when using dark theme.  I see this too and i would really like it to go away.  i switched to light theme for now.

Comment: Commenting just to express my mutual hatred of this "feature". Please let me know if you figure out how to get rid of it.

Comment: @zero01alpha I don't know when it was changed, but on Chrome `88.0.4324.96`  I don't see the white glow anymore, identical setup as when I made this post originally. Maybe updating your Chrome will fix it?